# How has the current ideology of the Democrats and Republicans contributed to the increased political polarization in the US?

Tags: united-states, political-spectrum

> Why has the U.S. become so much more polarized? Shapiro said it may be
> partly because, since the 1970s, major political parties have become
> increasingly aligned with certain ideologies, races and religious
> identities. For example, Republicans are now more likely to be
> religious, while Democrats are more likely to be secular.
>
> “*There’s evidence that within the U.S., the two major political
> parties have become more homogeneous in certain ways, including
> ideologically and socially*,” Shapiro said. “*So when you identify with
> a certain party and you’re looking across the aisle, the people you’re
> looking at are more different from you than they were a few decades
> ago.*” - [U.S. is polarizing faster than other democracies, study finds](https://www.brown.edu/news/2020-01-21/polarization)

As outlined in this study, can someone explain how the ideology of the Democrats and Republicans have evolved so much to supposedly lose common grounds (if any existed in the first place)? What parts of their individual and differing ideology has become extremist?

Comment: This doesn't have a clear question, it seems more like you are thinking aloud.  It's not clear what political *question* you have.  If you are asking "has US politics become more polarised" then the answer is surely "yes".    But if you are asking "is the right-wing more right wing than in the past" The answer is not possible, because there isn't a consistent definition of "right wing" that works across the world and across time.  For example, the idea of "republicanism" (ie having a president not a king) is an extreme **left-wing** position in the UK.

Comment: The question is for usa only, i edited. And the question is, are they becoming more extreme in their views and actions, or did they always have these views, and are the actions just due to being in the minority and internet exposure? Like, would they have taken the actions before, but didn't feel the need to.

Comment: Like ever since the tea party, was that new, or just a new minority? Reacting to Obama.

Comment: So I'm really asking if there is anything new and different about them. The increased polarization could have come from the changing views of the left, where the majority has become less bigotted. And less accepting of trickle down.

Comment: I could rephrase the question as like, has the increse in polarization come from changing views of the right or left?

Comment: You see, why is "banning nicknames" right wing, except that it is a policy of the right wing party?  Yes, policies constantly evolve.  Democrats used to be the pro-slavery, anti-civil rights party.  Before the 1970s gay sex was pretty much illegal everywhere in the USA, so yes, things do change.  The polarisation has come from changes on both wings.

Comment: Ok, so the question could be which party changed more to cause things like banning nicknames. There is some interplay between people's views and the party's views, yes. But I'm not asking whether banning nicknames is right wing, its like creationism being taught in schools, right wing enough.

Comment: And yes, people change, but you say things have become more polarized, so you would admit there is a question of which side changed more.

Comment: Please update the question in the question body not in comments. We want a really clear question. Also I don't think it's true. Just think about racial segregation that was once totally fine. It cannot get much more extreme than that really.

Comment: I guess that's an answer, saying they haven't gotten more extreme,  it just feels like it in ways since the majority view changed more. I don't think it's a question of whether the right wing has been accused of becoming more extreme, true or not.

Comment: I should change the main question or the body? I added edits to the body, for clarification

Comment: If I've made the question clear enough here in the comments, but it's not clear with edits in the body, feel free to edit.

Comment: I'd suggest rewriting.  That is don't add to the body, but [edit] it  Remove what is unclear an waffle.  Demonstrate what resources you have used (provide links to internet sites) Edit both the title and the body of the question.  Take care over spelling and capital letters.

Comment: Ok I tried, not sure if it's the topic influences the like of a question though.

Answer (score 5):

The polarisation is occuring as [both parties become more extreme.](https://www.pewresearch.org/politics/2014/06/12/political-polarization-in-the-american-public/)

But there is a lot to unpick here....

As the social and economic situation of the USA changes, then people will form opinions and these can be picked up and "packaged" as partisan opinions.

A viewpoint is only "extreme" when considered with reference to a "centre", and the centre of American opinion shifts.

To take an example, consider LGBTQ rights. Before the 1960s the question of LGBTQ rights would not be so much of an issue, since homosexuality (or the expression of it by men) was illegal. The notion of supporting same-sex marriage would be impossible.  I can't find data about support for same-sex marriage before 1996, nobody was even asking the question.

With homosexual relationships becoming legal, the question of marriage becomes something that one can reasonably have an opinion on. So a view that opposes same-sex marriage becomes more extreme because the centre has moved. As the centre moves, then positions that were once considered extreme become mainstream, and that leads some to push further.  So as the centre shifted from "Gay sex should be illegal" to "Gay sex should be tolerated", a new position appeared "Gay couples should be able to form unions".  As that view became more central, the view "Gay couples should be able to marry" become possible, and now that view is mainstream.

On the other hand, consider tax and spend.  Here the "centre" has [shifted towards the Republican position](https://www.csmonitor.com/USA/Politics/2011/0731/America-s-big-shift-right).  The debate has shifted from "how much to raise and who do we tax" to "what do we cut?", since any tax rise is politically unacceptable.  So a person espousing the tax policies of the 1970s would look increasingly extreme.

So there isn't a simple story here.  The centre moves and opinions can change from mainstream to extreme, or the extreme can become mainstream.

There isn't a simple flow from left to right either.

There is one general fact of left and right, and that the left wing is "progressive" while the right is "conservative".  And so the right wing will tend to hold onto notions from the past for longer than the left wing.  Sometimes, if the centre of politics is moving right, this can make left wing politics of yesteryear seem very different, whereas right wing politics is more about preserving aspects of the past.  You'll see words like "New" used a lot in progressive politics, whereas "traditional" is used by conservatives.

Comment: Might want to reference 2003's Lawrance v. Texas - as that was when homosexuality ceased being criminal throughout the entire country. Only 20 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the United States - as shown by Pew Research - is a two-party [system](https://www.pewresearch.org/politics/2022/08/09/as-partisan-hostility-grows-signs-of-frustration-with-the-two-party-system/) with half of the young adults saying they ‘wish there were more parties to choose from’. This polarization happens because of having two political parties where any extremes have to run as Republican or Democrat to even have a chance on the ballot. The [Washington](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/2021/03/01/break-up-two-party-system/) Post and [others](https://foreignpolicy.com/2019/10/19/us-democracy-two-party-system-replace-multiparty-republican-democrat/) [have](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-the-two-party-system-is-wrecking-american-democracy/) stated how it might be better if America can move beyond the two-party system, but both parties have restrictive ballot access laws for [third](https://www.forbes.com/2010/05/13/third-parties-fusion-voting-elections-opinions-columnists-bruce-bartlett.html?sh=71fbf95b5f7a) parties like a law in some areas that say third parties have to petition to get their names on a general [election](https://ballotpedia.org/Ballot_access_for_major_and_minor_party_candidates) ballot and payment of certain fees before being given access - [something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballot_access) the other two parties are probably not going to change anytime.

So basically, the part of the ideology of Democrats and Republicans to have a winner-take-all two-party system and intentionally preventing third parties from having an easy time running are what potentially lead to an increase in extremes.

Answer (score -1):

Current US polarization is almost entirely propaganda-driven, and propaganda (properly put) is almost entirely a feature of the US political Right. What I mean is that while we can debate whether Left-wing talking points are *reasonable* as proposed policy, they invariably have a factual basis. I may disagree with some of the more extreme Leftist suggestions about fiscal policy, but I can't really argue that the ever-increasing wealth gap doesn't exist or isn't a concern. But large swaths of Right-wing talking points are rooted in bizarre conspiracy theory, unfounded accusations of wrong-doing, outright lies, and strange and ever-shifting assertions of victimhood.

The Right-wing propaganda system began with FOX Opinion pundits capitalizing on the Ken Starr investigation, solidified through the Bush Administration, and then gradually spun out of control during the end of the Obama administration into Pizzagate, Q-Conspiracy, and Trumpism proper. The current state of polarization continues because the far Right instantly and brutally demonizes any disagreement with their positions. There is no equivalent behavior on the left, and trying to make this about 'both' sides is merely more disinformation.